# TestNG testsuite is not running from Jenkins it works from command prompt and eclipse

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

Have setup Jenkins for a Maven project. It got kicked of correctly.

Issue: When running TestNG test suite got called out but did not ran any selenium related test cases it ran other test cases where i just printed date in test suite. Successfully running of other test cases to me seems setup is correct. Below is POM snapshot. Out of 3 test case only one has selenium webpage call and only that cases is not passing even the page is not getting launched.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Compiler plug-in -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Below plug-in is used to execute tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>    
<dependencies>          
    <dependency>                
         <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
         <version>3.8.1</version>                               
         <scope>test</scope>                                
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
        <version>2.45.0</version>                               
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
        <version>6.8</version>                              
        <scope>test</scope>                                     
   </dependency>                
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: when you say it works from command prompt , how did you run it from command prompt? add the details

Comment: @Ravendra Singh you might want to share the selenium test case configuration(setup details) and how are you hosting Jenkins. This would clear out the connection you are trying to attempt to execute that test case.

Comment: Thanks for reply - @nullpointer - simple launch pagepublic class DEMOCI1_Test {  
     private WebDriver driver;  
  at-Test    
  public void launchpnet() throws InterruptedException {    
   driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
   String title = driver.getTitle();
   System.out.println("Page Title is:- "+title );   
  } 
  at-BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() { 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path//chromedriver.exe");   
      driver = new ChromeDriver();       
  }  
  at-AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
   driver.quit();   
  }  
}

Comment: @vishal -  mvn clean install -Pselenium-tests. It executed my selenium and unit test case ... but when i ran from jenkins it ran only unit test case, for selenium test case browser didnt launched .. and in my code where am trying to print the launch page name in this case assume google - it says access required.

Comment: @Ravendra Singh that is because your profile selenium-tests might not have been defined on your jenkins instance.